# Split a string at every return key

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

Beginner at javascript/coding

I need to split a string every time the enter key is pressed and store them in an array

```
I-0000-DV-301-0003
I-0000-DV-301-0002
I-0000-DV-301-0001

output:
array[0] = I-0000-DV-301-0003
array[1]=I-0000-DV-301-0002
...
```

I've tried string.split but i'm not sure how to use it with the 'enter' or 'return' key.

Thank you!

Comment: how do you get the string to split ?

Comment: `Every time time the enter key is pressed` in: A user interacts with an input field and presses enter? Or do you have a complete string and try to split every carriage return?

Comment: This should just be marked as a duplicate, unless further informations are specified. As long as no informations about how the input is provided are available, this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split on a newline `\n`:

```js
const str = `I-0000-DV-301-0003
I-0000-DV-301-0002
I-0000-DV-301-0001`;

const res = str.split("\n");

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score -1):

To split with enter or new line character use this

```
str.split("\n");
```